# The set of isotropic vectors contains the kernel of a Bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm studying linear algebra, specifically bilinear forms. I found many sources where it's said that
$$ker(g)\subseteq I(g)$$
where $I$ is the set of all isotropic vectors and $g$ is a bilinear form.

I can find some examples, but I fail to understand why this is true in every case, specifically, why the set of isotropic vectors can be bigger and always contains the kernel.

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space.

I define the kernel of a bilinear form as

$$ker(g)= [v\in V | g(v,w)=0 \forall w \in V] $$

and I define the set of all isotropic vectors as

$$ I= [v \in V | g(v,v)=0 \forall v\in V]$$

Comment: " why the set of isotropic vectors is always bigger" -- not always. They can be equal. The notation $\subseteq$ means "is either equal or a proper subset".

Comment: you're right, I'm going to correct the question

Answer (score 1):

If $v\in\ker(g)$, then, for each vector $w\in V$, $g(v,w)=0$. In particular, $g(v,v)=0$. In other words, $v\in I(g)$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is clear that if $g(v,w)=0$ for all $w\in V$, then a fortiori $g(v,v)=0$; therefore $\ker g\subseteq I(g)$. For a strict inclusion, you can think about $$g:\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R\\ g(v,w)=v_1w_1-v_2w_2=v^T\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&-1\end{pmatrix}w$$

for which $\ker g=\{(0,0)\}$ but $I(g)=\operatorname{span}\{(1,1)^T\}\cup \operatorname{span}\{(1,-1)^T\}$.

Comment: Thank you, very appreciated.